# Firebase Realtime Database data is coming even though it was deleted

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I deleted data from Firebase even though realtime database data is coming in. I am using Firebase for Unity. I wonder if Unity Firebase SDK has a store of all data? If it so, how can I delete local Firebase Data?

Comment: I'm not clear on what problem you're trying to solve. What would deleting local Firebase data accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the data is coming from the local disk cache, that Firebase *may* keep on Android/iOS devices if you [enable it](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-disk-persistence). If that is indeed the case, the simplest way to get rid of the data is to delete and reinstall  the app.